# Why are these jQuery statements at the top of the file breaking the ones below?

Tags: jquery

The **Jquery Accordion** part it is breaking the others below (**Nivo Slider** and **jPlayer**).

Like you can see in this website: http://alexchen.info/brianfunshine

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {
    /**
     * Jquery Accordion
     */
    $j('#list1b').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#list1c').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#list1d').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    $j('#list1e').accordion({
        autoheight: false
    });
    /**
     * Nivo Slider
     */
    $j('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({max: 310, duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
    /**
     * Jplayer
     */
    var Playlist = function(instance, playlist, options) {
        var self = this;

        this.instance = instance; // String: To associate specific HTML with this playlist
        this.playlist = playlist; // Array of Objects: The playlist
        this.options = options; // Object: The jPlayer constructor options for this playlist

        this.current = 0;

        this.cssId = {
            jPlayer: "jquery_jplayer_",
            interface: "jp_interface_",
            playlist: "jp_playlist_"
        };
        this.cssSelector = {};

        $j.each(this.cssId, function(entity, id) {
            self.cssSelector[entity] = "#" + id + self.instance;
        });

        if(!this.options.cssSelectorAncestor) {
            this.options.cssSelectorAncestor = this.cssSelector.interface;
        }

        $j(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer(this.options);

        $j(this.cssSelector.interface + " .jp-previous").click(function() {
            self.playlistPrev();
            $j(this).blur();
            return false;
        });

        $j(this.cssSelector.interface + " .jp-next").click(function() {
            self.playlistNext();
            $j(this).blur();
            return false;
        });
    };

    Playlist.prototype = {
        displayPlaylist: function() {
            var self = this;
            $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + " ul").empty();
            for (i=0; i < this.playlist.length; i++) {
                var listItem = (i === this.playlist.length-1) ? "<li class='jp-playlist-last'>" : "<li>";
                listItem += "<a href='#' id='" + this.cssId.playlist + this.instance + "_item_" + i +"' tabindex='1'>"+ this.playlist[i].name +"</a>";

                // Create links to free media
                if(this.playlist[i].free) {
                    var first = true;
                    listItem += "<div class='jp-free-media'>(";
                    $j.each(this.playlist[i], function(property,value) {
                        if($j.jPlayer.prototype.format[property]) { // Check property is a media format.
                            if(first) {
                                first = false;
                            } else {
                                listItem += " | ";
                            }
                            listItem += "<a id='" + self.cssId.playlist + self.instance + "_item_" + i + "_" + property + "' href='" + value + "' tabindex='1'>" + property + "</a>";
                        }
                    });
                    listItem += ")</span>";
                }

                listItem += "</li>";

                // Associate playlist items with their media
                $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + " ul").append(listItem);
                $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + i).data("index", i).click(function() {
                    var index = $j(this).data("index");
                    if(self.current !== index) {
                        self.playlistChange(index);
                    } else {
                        $j(self.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("play");
                    }
                    $j(this).blur();
                    return false;
                });

                // Disable free media links to force access via right click
                if(this.playlist[i].free) {
                    $j.each(this.playlist[i], function(property,value) {
                        if($j.jPlayer.prototype.format[property]) { // Check property is a media format.
                            $j(self.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + i + "_" + property).data("index", i).click(function() {
                                var index = $j(this).data("index");
                                $j(self.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + index).click();
                                $j(this).blur();
                                return false;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        playlistInit: function(autoplay) {
            if(autoplay) {
                this.playlistChange(this.current);
            } else {
                this.playlistConfig(this.current);
            }
        },
        playlistConfig: function(index) {
            $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + this.current).removeClass("jp-playlist-current").parent().removeClass("jp-playlist-current");
            $j(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + index).addClass("jp-playlist-current").parent().addClass("jp-playlist-current");
            this.current = index;
            $j(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("setMedia", this.playlist[this.current]);
        },
        playlistChange: function(index) {
            this.playlistConfig(index);
            $j(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("play");
        },
        playlistNext: function() {
            var index = (this.current + 1 < this.playlist.length) ? this.current + 1 : 0;
            this.playlistChange(index);
        },
        playlistPrev: function() {
            var index = (this.current - 1 >= 0) ? this.current - 1 : this.playlist.length - 1;
            this.playlistChange(index);
        }
    };

    var videoPlaylist = new Playlist("1", [
        {
            name:"Big Buck Bunny Trailer",
            free:true,
            m4v:"http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v",
            ogv:"http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv",
            poster:"http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"
        },
        {
            name:"Finding Nemo Teaser",
            m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352_h264aac.m4v",
            ogv: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352.ogv",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Finding_Nemo_Teaser_640x352.png"
        },
        {
            name:"Incredibles Teaser",
            m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272_h264aac.m4v",
            ogv: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272.ogv",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Incredibles_Teaser_640x272.png"
        }
    ], {
        ready: function() {
            videoPlaylist.displayPlaylist();
            videoPlaylist.playlistInit(false); // Parameter is a boolean for autoplay.
        },
        ended: function() {
            videoPlaylist.playlistNext();
        },
        play: function() {
            $j(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "ogv, m4v"
    });

    var audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2", [
        {
            name:"Tempered Song",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Lentement",
            free:true,
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-03-Lentement.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-03-Lentement.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Lismore",
            free:true,
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-04-Lismore.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04-Lismore.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"The Separation",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-05-The-separation.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-05-The-separation.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Hidden",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg"
        },
        {
            name:"Beside Me",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-06-Beside-me.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-06-Beside-me.ogg"
        }

    ], {
        ready: function() {
            audioPlaylist.displayPlaylist();
            audioPlaylist.playlistInit(false); // Parameter is a boolean for autoplay.
        },
        ended: function() {
            audioPlaylist.playlistNext();
        },
        play: function() {
            $j(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "oga, mp3"
    });
});
```

Any suggestion of why?

Comment: Are you putting your video's within the accordion or within the menu?? If so you may need to set up the .live function. What may be happening is that your event is not being run because it is within a function that doesn't use .live.

It's hard to tell without the html though, can you post it as well??

Comment: You can narrow down the problem, I'm sure. The provided code is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this:

```
$j('#list1b').accordion({
    autoheight: false
});
$j('#list1c').accordion({
    autoheight: false
});
$j('#list1d').accordion({
    autoheight: false
});
$j('#list1e').accordion({
    autoheight: false
});
```

Could become this:

```
$j('#list1b, #list1c, #list1d, #list1e').accordion(
  {autoHeight : false}      
);
```

NOTE: the 'autoHeight' rather than the 'autoheight'

Comment: And I think that this should have been a comment. You're right, but it doesn't solve the question. Also I prefer the OP's curly brace placement.

Comment: I think its the 'autoHeight' rather than 'autoheight' that is the solution